# How to get the value of spinner from onBindViewHolder

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the value of `spinner` from `onBindViewHolder` and set it to a textView. Here is what I tried.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final Post post= mPost.get(position);
    Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage())
            .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image))
            .into(holder.post_image);
    String pTimeStamp = mPost.get(position).getPublishTime();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(pTimeStamp));
    final String pTime = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", calendar).toString();
    holder.mTimestamp.setText(pTime);
    if(post.getTitle().equals(""))
    {
        holder.title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.title.setText(post.getTitle());
    }
    holder.servings.setText(post.getServings()+" servings");
    holder.hrs.setText(post.getHours()+"");
    holder.mins.setText(post.getMinutes()+"");

    holder.mealType.setText(post.getMeal().getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

However, this line is causing the app to crash (with no error message):

```
holder.mealType.setText(post.getMeal().getSelectedItem().toString());
```

I tried this way also, but it still doesn't work:

```
String m = post.getMeal().getSelectedItem().toString();
holder.mealType.setText(m);
```

[The value of the `spinner` is already saved in the database:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsfzU.png)

All I'm trying to do is to get that value and assign it to the textView which is in my case `mealType`.

This is how I registered the spinner:

```
 spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItemText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
             
                    Snipper1 =  spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    SharedPreferences sharedPref1 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreference1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref1.edit();
                    editor.putString("Spinner", Snipper1);  // Pick a key here.
                    editor.apply();
              }
          }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
            }
        });
```

here is my setter and getter:

```
 public void setMeal(Spinner meal) {
        Meal = meal;
    }
    public Spinner getMeal() {
        return Meal;
    }
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Did you register your spinner via ```findViewById()```? Did you set a default value for the spinner value?

Comment: yes I registered it using findViewById(), but in another activity. all I'm trying to achieve now is retrieving the value of the spinner that has already been saved in a database and set it to a textView

Comment: When the app crashes, reload the app and crash it again. Then go to LogCat and select "error" filter. What is the top level error message?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a NullPointerException lol.

Comment: ok yes now it shows this error message, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.widget.Spinner.getSelectedItem()' on a null object reference

Comment: Yes, so it is a null issue. Basically, the Spinner is not registered.

Comment: Your either have to register it in host Activity or main Activity for it to carry over to your host Activity.

Comment: I have it registered in another activity where the value is taken from the user, not in the Adapter class.

Comment: Yes, so in that same activity, create a get method. Because each Activity is separate, so data doesn't carry over unless you pass it as Extra/ Bundle or make clever use of getter methods.

Comment: As far as your running Activity is concerned, there is no Spinner to refer to.

Comment: I have getMeal() which is a getter method, I tried using getters more than once and it worked, only the one for spinner didn't work. I will try to create a method in the activity I registered spinner in. thank you for in advance

Comment: Would you be able to share the code where you have actually set value to your Spinner? At this point, the problem is very abstract and we can only speculate.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You mention that your TextView is Meal, but then in your set & get methods, it is set a type of Spinner. If these are separate, don't name them the same to avoid confusion in general. Also, name all variables with the first character being a small caps. Always. Java runs on some conventions, so it would be easier for everyone including you once you start developing more complex applications.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. it is only a TextView, I changed its name now so it would be easier to understand my code

Comment: There we go. Don't pass the Spinner, pass the *value* contained within the Spinner. You can't pass a whole View Widget to another Activity like that.

Comment: The other Activity didn't register the Spinner, so it doesn't 'own' it. The Activity is therefore just confused as to where this widget just came from. Activities are not linked like member of a Class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the class where you are actually setting a value to your Spinner. This will be a `get()` method, which will return the value currently in the Spinner. Then access the value from another class via calling the `get()` method of the generated instance of that class.
Don't pass Spinner, but the *value* of the Spinner.

```
public String getSpinnerValue()
{
    return yourSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
}
```

Comment: I tried your method. it still shows the same error message. 'java.lang.Object android.widget.Spinner.getSelectedItem()' on a null object reference. The spinner is registered in onCreate() method. I don't know why the error still exist even though the Spinner is registered.

Comment: It is very difficult to adress this problem by just viewing sections of your code. Would you be able to share it on github? Like is Snipper1 a String or what? And you should store Spinner value to a string during onItemSelected method execution so it is a concrete value. and then return that string in your get method.

Comment: Yes, Spinner1 is a String. I passed it in the get method. Now the error is gone. but I have a question. since Spinner1 value is initialized within onItemSelected method, when I use it to pass it in my get method, will it still have the same value that was assigned to it within the onItemSelected?

Comment: now the code is working but when I access the method from the other activity and assign it to the textView, it doesn't show. I think it is an empty string because in my get method I only passed the Spinner1 String

Comment: well you have to update Spinner1 string everytime inside the onItemSelected

Comment: Spinner1 should be initialized *outside* the method.

Comment: Spinner1 should only be updated *inside* the method. The onSelectedItem method.